# Cassandra UDF with Java throwing error on usage of stream

Tags: cassandra, user-defined-functions, cqlsh

I am trying to write a `UDF in Cassandra` using **Java**.
I have two list of integers with one to one mapping i.e., first item in the first list corresponds to the first item in the second list. This is how my data is stored in Cassandra table under two columns of list type.
My UDF

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mykeyspace.get_thread(list1 List<int>, list2 List<int>)
CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
RETURNS List<int>
LANGUAGE java
AS '
Map<Integer, Integer> intermediatemap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
   if (!intermediatemap.containsKey(i))
       intermediatemap.put(list1.get(i), list2.get(i));
}
List<Integer> commentids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
intermediatemap.entrySet().stream()
       .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed())
       .forEachOrdered(x -> commentids.add(x.getKey()));
if (commentids.size() > 8)
   return commentids.subList(0, 8);
else
   return commentids;
';
```

This is running all good as code. However, when I execute this on `cqlsh` I am getting error saying

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Java source compilation failed:
Line 8: The type java.util.stream.Stream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
Line 8: The method stream() from the type Collection<Map.Entry<Integer,Integer>> refers to the missing type Stream
```

Is there any problem with the Cassandra version I am using? I am running the Cassandra on my local MAC machine inside a docker. I have tried with `3.11.2` and the image with `latest` tag.
Also, UDF function is enabled I am able to run simple UDF functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use only classes that are explicitly defined in the allowed classes list inside Cassandra, and not in the disallowed list defined.  If you look to the source code for Cassandra 3.11.2, [you can see that `java.utils.stream` is in the disallowed list](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.11.2/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/cql3/functions/UDFunction.java#L154), so you can't use it inside UDF/UDA.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have modified my code to not use streams.